# CRATE 0.28.0.1 and elasticsearch-cloud-aws plugin compatibility

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, crate

We are going to use CRATE with elasticsearch-cloud-aws plugin for ES to create backups.
It looks like current version 0.28.0.1 (from deb package) has an issue with run time environment for aws plugin.

It says:

> {1.0.1}: Initialization Failed ...
>   - NoClassDefFoundError[org/elasticsearch/common/collect/Lists]
>     ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.common.collect.Lists]

It makes Crate incompatible with aws backup plugin.
It would be great to have any aws-based backup plugin on board, because it is very convenient.

How could we manage to backup our data on a daily basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an compatibility problem with elasticsearch-cloud-aws and ES >= 1.0.0 (crate 0.28.0 actually uses ES 1.0.1), Lists was removed from the ES package in favour of com.google.common.collect.Lists.

See https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/issues/57

Comment: Thank you, we will recheck it. 
We've been using backup-aws plugin on top of ES 1.0.1 for a while, it works fine.