# Use Crate SQL module(plugin) in Elasticsearch

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, crate

I am using Elasticsearch on linux sever but Quering is a little bit difficult

because form of query is not SQL structure.

In crate, there is a sql plugin, so I put this plugin into my own Elasticsearch

Is it possible?

If not, how can I adopt Crate SQL Plugin into Elasticsearch?

Thanks

Comment: Note: you also can check out the [Elasticsearch 6.3 release, now (June 2018) with native SQL support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50889538/6309). Not *exactly* Crate SQL though.

Answer (score 2):

Jehyun:

Crate has evolved from being an Elasticsearch plugin to a complete software stack.  I don't believe that you can simply add a plugin to Elasticsearch to gain SQL-like queries.  You would need to [transition your cluster to Crate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244011/es-to-crate-data-transfer) in order to use SQL queries.

Of course, you should test this process on a non-production system first.

Comment: Thank you for answering. 
I've tried build Crate SQL Plugin which is located in [github](https://github.com/crate/crate/tree/master/sql)  but build with gradle doesn't work..

Comment: In github - CRATE SQL Plugin, there is a development document. As this guide, it can be build by maven, but no pom.xml file in same folder